# VSCode workspace automatically include all subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

Is it possible to make a VSCode workspace automatically include all children subfolders as part of the workspace? I'm adding several folders in programmatically and would like them to automatically populate when I open the workspace.

I've spent the past hour trying to figure out how to accomplish this to no avail.

Comment: you can write a simple script to modify the `.workspace` file

Comment: That's valid, I could do that. I was just hoping there was an automatic syntax way of doing it. From what I read there doesn't seem to be anything like that which I feel is a lack of oversight. Specifically since I don't see any reason why a wildcard syntax should not be used in the .workspace file